# When compiling without dynamic RTL I get EAccessViolation

Tags: c++, c++builder

In Borland C++ Builder 6, when I try to make a standalone app by unchecking 'use dynamic RTL' I get EAccessViolation.
MWE is:

```
#include <vcl.h>
pragma hdrstop
#include "fstream.h"
#include "Unit1.h"
pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
ifstream pies;
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{}
```

in which i just have a plain blank project with

```
ifstream pies;
```

added to it.

It breaks down in _STLP_IOS_C:
in

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits>
basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ios()
  : ios_base(),
    _M_fill(_STLP_NULL_CHAR_INIT(_CharT)), _M_streambuf(0), _M_tied_ostream(0)
{}
```

pointing ot the

```
      : ios_base(),
```

How can I workaround this? I need an app I could move somewhere else, but I do also need fstream.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a compiler from 2002? That's downright ancient in C++ terms...

Comment: People don't always have a choice.  I myself still use BCB 6 at my day job, because the higher ups at the company would never allow us to upgrade to newer versions over the years.  Not from a lack of trying on our part, I might add.

Comment: @Remy : You have my sympathy. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: it is not so bad.  BCB 6 was a fairly solid product.  Sure, the IDE crashes on occasion, but so far we have not had other problems with it.  And all of the third-party components we use still support BCB 6.  We have software that targets multiple Windows versions, including Windows 7, so there is no problems calling newer APIs when needed. Redesigning an MDI-style app into a TDI-style app just to get better Win7 Taskbar and Thumbnail integration was a PITA, though. I ended up borrowing a lot of hints from the VCL's `TApplication.MainFormOnTaskbar` implementation from later versions.

Comment: what about checking in on another machine (for example, a virtual one) with bcb6 installed?

Answer (score 2):

To make a standalone app, you have to disable both the "Use Dynamic RTL" and "Build with Runtime Packages" options.

Comment: I surely do, thats where the problem comes. When I disable both of them I get the formentioned problem.

Comment: Works fine for me in BCB6 when I use your code snippet as-is.  So something in your project is messed up.  Maybe you are linking with a bad/incorrect library or something.  Have you tried using the debugger yet to find where the AV is occuring?

Comment: Added debugger info, hope it will help you help me.

Comment: Not really.  What is happening inside of `ios_base()` that is crashing?  You need to debug deeper. If it helps, don't declare the `ifstream` as a global variable like you are. Make it a member of your `TForm1` class instead, so it gets dynamically constructed in heap memory after the program is up and running. If that still crashes, then declare the `ifstream` variant as an `ifstream*` pointer, use 'new ifstream' to instantiate it manually, and then you can step through the constructor with the debugger line by line until you fine the culprit.